# How to install mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3 in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: apt, 22.04, gtk3, mingw32

I am using MingW32 and am trying to install the package `mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3`, however, that's not available via the `apt install` and it looks like you could only install it via `pacman`. Could someone show me the way to make it work (possibly without using MSYS2, as I pretty much got everything working except I'm missing the GTK3 part).

Namely, I need this package but it looks like you could only get it off MSYS2 using `pacman`: https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3

Environment/Setup:

- Windows 11
- Ubuntu 22.04 (WSL2)

  - `apt install mingw-w64`

I am able to compile all my CLI executables inside the Ubuntu 22.04 with MingW32 and running it fine in Windows.. I also have 2 small GUI applications that I want to get them to work too and they uses GTK3. I am able to compile them too but only in Windows using MSYS2, but I really want to just compile/build everything off Ubuntu environment to keep everything simple.

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/mingw-w64 is found in Ubuntu repositories, why not use it?

Comment: Because there is no gtk3? I am already using `mingw-w64-x86-64`

Comment: Are you on Windows (+WSL) or on actual Linux? Where did you get your existing mingw32?

Comment: I am on Windows running Ubuntu 22.04 (WSL2), I've updated my original post to describe my setup. I was going to try to install `pacman` in Ubuntu and then just maybe try to install `mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3` but I read that it is not recommended to use `pacman`.

Comment: Please use @username when replying, otherwise I don't get notifications.

Comment: Forget about WSL, use MSYS2 directly on Windows. Cross-compilation (which is what you're attempting now, aka producing apps for one OS while using another) is more complex that just developing on the correct OS in the first place. [Installation guide](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for your input, but I already know and could build directly in Windows. The whole point is to avoid having to separate building environments. MSYS2 is basically just running it in another simulated environment using mingw, which is pretty much what I am using in Ubuntu. In fact, I could build the CLI exe just fine, I am only missing the GTK portion. If you need to build it directly on a different platform, it is not "cross-compilation" now is it?

Comment: You end up with an extra build environment one way or another. I [made a tool](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2) to download MSYS2 packages on Linux, you can use it to install GTK. It may or may not be compatible with MinGW provided by Ubuntu, but the recommended compilation method doesn't rely on external MinGW. I can write a full answer if needed.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that would be great. If I read your repo correctly, lets say I need `mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3`, I would clone your repo, type in `make install mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3` and the MSYS2 package would become magically usable like the rest of the mingw packages?

Comment: The package will be installed to the current directory, which you then have to add to compiler search paths.

Comment: Did my tool work correctly for you?

Answer (score 1):

I've made [Quasi-MSYS2](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2), which helps download MSYS2 packages on Linux.

```sh
sudo apt install make wget tar zstd gpg

git clone https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2
cd quasi-msys2/
make install _gtk4   # equivalent to `make install mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk4`
```

This downloads GTK4 to the current directory (`./root/mingw64/`) for you to use.

But there's a problem: MinGW comes in different flavors, and the flavors provided by MSYS2 may or may not be compatible with the flavor provided by Ubuntu.

The recommended build method doesn't depend on external MinGW. Instead I suggest using Clang, which can work with any MinGW flavor, if provided the right libraries (which we download from MSYS2).

```sh
sudo apt install wine   # Optional.

# Install latest Clang
wget https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh
chmod +x llvm.sh
sudo ./llvm.sh
rm llvm.sh

# Install more packages
make install _gcc _gdb    # We won't be using GCC, but we need libraries that come with it.

# Opens a new shell with the right environment variables configured.
env/shell.sh
```

Then, testing on Hello World from [here](https://www.gtk.org/docs/getting-started/hello-world):

```sh
# Notice `pkg-config` picking up the correct libraries.
win-clang++ hello_world.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk4`
# This opens the app in Wine:
./a.exe
```